# Apache2 not starting on Ubuntu Server 17.04

Tags: networking, server, apache2, network-manager, juju

Not able to restart apache2.

checking `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` got this result:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1627/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      4486/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      4486/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1627/nginx: master
```

after trying to reload apache2 with `systemctl reload apache2`got this message:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===   
Authentication is required to reload 'apache2.service'.  
Authenticating as: Name Surname,,, (Username)  
Password:   
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===  
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

Trying several Time to reload the Services, installed / updates services:

> - OpenSSH Server
> - PHP7
> - MySQL
> - phpMyAdmin
> - Apache Tomcat8
> - FTP (vsftpd)

Other messages that could help solve out my issue checking Status
`systemctl status apache2.service`:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d  
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-24 20:03:47 CEST; 29min ago   
  Process: 6623 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)<br><br>
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer apachectl[6623]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer apachectl[6623]: Invalid command 'ServerAdmin=gianni.alagna@modular.codes', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer apachectl[6623]: Action 'start' failed.  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer apachectl[6623]: The Apache error log may have more information.  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.  
Apr 24 20:03:47 mcServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
Apr 24 20:18:33 mcServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.  
Apr 24 20:18:35 mcServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

**Additional Note**
I'm trying to setup a WebHost server for own Webbased (php) Applications.

Comment: Isn't `nginx` listening on port `80`? try `systemctl stop nginx` then start apache.

Comment: `systemctl stop nginx`is stopping the service as expected, but after starting `sudo systemctl reload apache2.service` still got error message:  *apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.*

Comment: `systemctl status nginx.service` ...   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-24 21:21:10 CEST; 15s ago...  Process: 25502 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25662 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25659 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/

Comment: @Ravexina: **Update:** Apache2 finally startet with `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service` and after stopping **nginx** with `systemctl stop nginx` but **nginx** won't restart now..

Comment: It's because both of them wants to listen on port 80 which is not possible, you should change one of them to listen somewhere else like 8080.

Comment: @Ravexina Changing the Ports to 8080 on **nginx.conf** won't work. Service still not active after `service nginx reload`

Comment: stop both of them, start nginx; make sure nginx is running at 8080 the run apache ;)

Comment: @Ravexina: are Ports settings for **nginx** defined somewhere else in `*.conf`files as on **nginx.conf**? starting the first service, implicate the failure of the other.

Comment: Have look at [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/368868/how-can-i-make-nginx-use-port-8080-instead-of-80).

Comment: @Ravexina: already tried out this solution. Won't work for me. Setting up the host, still can't operate both services together. Getting mad about... sitll working on all day long. ;)

Comment: Stop both of them, make sure `nginx` setting is as above link, start `nginx`, then run `sudo netstat -peanut | grep nginx` let me know what the output is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57652/discussion-between-gianni-and-ravexina).

Answer (score 0):

Solution by working around with support by @Nadav Tasher:

Nginx won't work properly! Two services (nginx-apache2) won't work same timely! Running Apache2 has fixed the issue permanently!